# FullCalendar v4 - How get currentStart, currentEnd in eventSources

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

Is possible or how get properties `currentStart` and `currentEnd`, but "in" `eventSources: [events: function(fetchInfo, ...)]`.

**Sample**

```
                eventSources: [
                    {
                        events: function (fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) {

                            let url = '{{ route("disparoevento.eventos") }}';

                            // formdata
                            let formdata = new FormData();

                            // month current
                            formdata.append('currentStart', currentStart);
                            formdata.append('currentEnd', currentEnd);

                            // calendar range
                            formdata.append('activeStart', fetchInfo.startStr);
                            formdata.append('activeEnd', fetchInfo.endStr);
                        },
                    }
                ],
```

The `fetchInfo` return only `end` (equivalent to activeEnd) and `start` (equivalent to activeStart).

Although not the problem, I need to send these 4 properties (currentStart, currentEnd,  activeStart, activeEnd) by POST during "init" of FullCalendar.

Comment: What are you defining is "currentStart" and "currentEnd" exactly? Are you talking about the properties of the View object (as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-object)? Please make it fully clear. Anyway...why do you need those properties? It should not be necessary as far as I can see. What will your server do differently with this information? You could always get it easily by simply getting the current view object (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-view) but I can't see why you would want or need to.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion and I had previously read this link, however, based on this link, I would only have the object, "after" the init of the FullCalendar, that is, during the "eventSources" event, I haven't yet FullCalendar instance.

Comment: Please elaborate your question, what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: Oh yes that's a good point, it might not have rendered yet. But, again **why** do you even need this extra data? I can't understand what the purpose would be. You already have `start` and `end` from the fetchInfo. Why is that not enough?

Comment: Precisely, I need the "current" calendar month, evidently not liberally the current month of year, but current calendar month, since the `start` and `end` can usually be between two months.